# Can an event be semi-dependent?

Tags: probability

I learned about dependent events and independent events and how to calculate the probability of two dependent events (such as drawing an ace after having drawn a three from a deck of cards) and independent events (rolling two sixes in a row on a six-sided die.)

Can events lie somewhere on a spectrum of dependence? I'm working on a genetics project and I'm wondering about the dependence of two risk alleles. The probability of the average human (worldwide) having risk factor 1 might be 0.03. The probability of the average human (worldwide) having risk factor 2 might be 0.10.

As presented, these are independent events. However, in some regions of the world, you might be more likely to have risk factor 2 if you also have risk factor 1. Would this make the events semi-dependent? Or would this 3rd factor (region) be another event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a way, it seems like there is another, third variable which influences your first two - whether they will be dependent. In that case, your first variable is dependent on both the second and third variable.

$P(\text{risk factor 1} | \text{risk factor 2} \cap \text{region})$.

For ex., in region 1 the two risk factors may be independent, but in region 2 they are dependent. You would capture this with the additional factor for region.

Comment: Very helpful way to look at this. Does "more likely" affect the dependence? You can be from this region and have riskfactor1 and not riskfactor2, but you're more likely to have both risk factors than people from other regions.

Comment: @Melanie Are you asking for the conditional probability of $P(\text{risk factor 1}|\text{region})$?